# electron react application multiple child windows, can only open one child window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have managed to open one childwindow in my react electron application, but I would like to open more than one child window. I've tried naming the childwindow framename dynamically with props, but that doesn't work either.

Here is child window class component:

```
export default class ChildWindow extends Component {
containerEl = document.createElement('div');
styleEl = document.createElement('style');
externalWindow = null;

componentDidMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', 'ChildWindow');
    
    if (this.externalWindow)
    {
        this.containerEl.style.height = '100vh';
        this.containerEl.style.width = '100vw';
        this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
        this.externalWindow.document.body.style.margin = '0';
        this.externalWindow.onunload = () => this.props.onClose();
    }
}

render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
}
}
```

Here is the new-window code setup in the electron.js file:

```
    mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) => {
    if (frameName === 'ChildWindow') {
        event.preventDefault();
        Object.assign(options, {
            // parent: mainWindow,
            height: 700,
            width: 400,
            minHeight: 700,
            minWidth: 400,
            resizable: false,
            frame: false,
            webPreferences: {
                enableRemoteModule: true,
                nodeIntegration: true,
                webSecurity: false,
                nativeWindowOpen: true
            }
        });
        const newWindow = new BrowserWindow(options);
        event.newGuest = newWindow;
    }
});
```

Also here the code where I use the childwindow component in my functional class:

```
                <ChildWindow
                    onClose={closeCaptchaSolver}
                >
                    <p>hoi</p>
                </ChildWindow>
```